# Retrieve contents from broken <a> tags using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a website and retrieve the texts that contain Hyper link.
For eg:

`<a href="www.example.com">This is an Example</a>`

I need to retrieve "This is an Example", which I am able to do for pages that dont have broken  tags. I am unable to retrieve in following case:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href = "http:\\www.google.com">Google<br>
<a href = "http:\\www.example.com">Example</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In such cases it the code is unable to retrieve Google because of the broken  tag that links google and only gives me "Example". Is there a way to also retrieve "Google"?

My code is here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer

f = open("sol.html","r")

soup = BeautifulSoup(f,parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
for link in soup.findAll('a',text=True):
    print link.renderContents();
```

Please note sol.html contains the above given html code itself.

Thanks
- AJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `text=True` from your code and it should work just fine:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
... <html>
... <body>
... <a href = "http:\\www.google.com">Google<br>
... <a href = "http:\\www.example.com">Example</a>
... </body>
... </html>
... ''')
>>> [a.get_text().strip() for a in soup.find_all('a')]
[u'Google', u'Example']
>>> [a.get_text().strip() for a in soup.find_all('a', text=True)]
[u'Example']
```

Comment: Thanks, its just about there. When I tried the code as you suggested i get the following output: 
[u'Google\nExample', u'Example']

Just trying to see why the \nExample. My modified code below:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer

f = open("sol.html","r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
print [a.get_text().strip() for a in soup.find_all('a')]

Comment: No, the additional text "\nExample" still gets appended

Comment: @AjayNair: Using the exact code that I used? What version of Python and BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: Rewriting the above comment(deleted now) for better readability:
Yes, exactly the same code. I am using Python 2.7 and BS4. My code as tested on python interpreter:
`>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(
'''<html> 
... <body> 
... <a href = "http:\\www.google.com">Google<br> 
... <a href = "http:\\www.example.com">Example</a> 
... </body> 
... </html> 
... ''') 
>>> [a.get_text().strip() for a in soup.find_all('a')] [u'Google\nExample', u'Example'] >>> `

Comment: @AjayNair: That's really odd. The only thing I can think of is for you to try installing `html5lib`.

Comment: It is working now. But I think at the cost of parsing the entire document (will need to figure out the alternatives for using soupstrainer, if u have any suggestions most welcome! ) but my original problem has been answered. Removing Text=true and installing html5lib works for me !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<html>
<body>
<a href = "http:\\www.google.com">Google<br>
<a href = "http:\\www.example.com">Example</a>
</body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link.string != None:
        print link.string
```

Here's the output when i ran the code:

```
Example
```

Just replace `text` with `text = open('sol.html').read()`, or whatever it is you need to go there.

Comment: Hi, I want to find both Google and Example. Currently my code also gives Example.

Comment: Oh sorry i understand now. Well, you'll need to just fix the broken links i guess, or use [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), I dont know how else you could do it.